# Neo4j super crazy auto index issue

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I use rest api to create nodes, 
Ive auto index for node's "Name" and "ObjectType" property.

it works gr8 before.
but I found it doesn't index some nodes recently.
some nodes only index "ObjectType", which means cypher below works:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(ObjectType="User") 
where id(n) =123
```

but this will not work:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(Name="demouser") 
where id(n) =123
```

if I change the Name from "demouser" to something like "anotheruser", still not in node_auto_index.
the only work around is change demouser to a number like 123, then change it back to "demouser",
then I can query it with node_auto_index(Name="demouser").

I really don't know what is going on. and I cannot find all nodes which not been auto indexed. 
I'm using neo4j 1.9.4

updated with neo4j properties

```
# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=Name,ObjectType 
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

keep_logical_logs=true 
online_backup_enabled=true 
online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362 
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

thanks

Comment: 1) post your neo4j.properties 2) be aware that changing config does not trigger automatic reindex on pre-existing nodes/rels. 3) config changes done via REST API/Java API are *not* persistent.

Comment: just updated my question. I didnt changed the configuration in a  very long time span. and it still works with 99% nodes.

Comment: can you create a reproducible case for this? If so, I consider this being a bug.

Comment: you can force reindexing of a node by setting a property with the pre-existing value

Comment: I will try to reproduce it. as I mentioned, ive done some force indexing for nodes, no lucky, must change the property to another type or delete the property then add it back.